# SMTP client StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm creating a massmailing program basically, and the problem is that if I do it without threads, it obviously freeze and it needs to be able to show user the progress. Without using another class/object it works perfectly fine.
I get a stackoverflowexception:

```
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

on

```
this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
```

NOTICE: This can probably be missleading because I haven't even created the thread yet but it still get's stackoverflowexception.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Mass_Mail
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        Worker work = new Worker();

        public List<String> succed = new List<String>();
        public List<String> failed = new List<String>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog(); //Skapa och definiera openfiledialog

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); //sätt startmappen till skrivbordet
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"; //textfiler.
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {


                        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
                            String line;
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                textBox2.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
                            }

                }
                    }
             catch (Exception ex) {
                 MessageBox.Show("Kunde inte öppna  " + ex.Message);
             }

        }

}

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // work.sendmail(textBox6.Text);
        }



    }
    public class Worker
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            string[] lines = frm1.textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                sendmail(lines[i]);
            }
        }
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        public void sendmail(String mail)
        {
            try
            {

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(frm2.textBox1.Text, int.Parse(frm2.textBox2.Text));
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(frm1.textBox3.Text, mail);
                client.Timeout = decimal.ToInt32(frm2.numericUpDown1.Value);
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                switch (frm2.comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        client.EnableSsl = true;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        client.EnableSsl = false;
                        break;
                }

                msg.Subject = frm1.textBox4.Text;
                msg.Body = frm1.textBox5.Text;
                msg.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                client.Send(msg);
                frm1.succed.Add(mail);
                frm1.label6.Text = "Lyckades: " + frm1.succed.Count.ToString();
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR! " + ex);
                frm1.failed.Add(mail);
                frm1.label7.Text = "Misslyckades: " + frm1.failed.Count.ToString();
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR! " + e);
                frm1.failed.Add(mail);
                frm1.label7.Text = "Misslyckades: " + frm1.failed.Count.ToString();
            }


        }
    }

}
```

I'm going to create a thread of DoWork. I have never done anything like this and I know that the code is pretty bad at the moment. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
I'm also really new to C# and multi-threading at all. 
Form2 only consists of textboxes etc to contain the SMTP settings, no code there.

EDIT:
If I don't create a new object

```
Worker work = new Worker();
```

it works perfectly fine!

Comment: The line you say is causing the error isn't included in your code sample at all

Comment: Because I don't know which one it is. The error is caused here: this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown(); but that's because the threads go in a stackoverflow state.

Comment: Yes, then please show us the code around `this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();` - because that's where the error is.

Comment: It's in Form2.Designer.cs and it's inside InitializeComponent().

Comment: The error is not to do with threads; it's an error that occurs when a method call causes infinite recursion. Whatever code is calling `this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();` is itself being called by something else. Most likely in your case, an OnChangedEvent on one of your controls. The line `this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();` itself is not a problem, it's just the furthest it gets before it runs out of stack frames. Because it's happened when adding the Worker class, it's likely on `label6` or `label7` (which is changed by the method)

Comment: I'm about to head off - but I would advise you to examine all places that call `DoWork`. Stick a break point at the start of `DoWork` and hit `F5` a few times when it breaks. Look at the stack frame - you should see a lot of repeating methods - then examine those and find out which ones are causing the infinite recursion.

Comment: `Form1 frm1 = new Form1(); Form2 frm2 = new Form2();` in your worker won't do what you seem to expect. Pass a reference to the already instantiated forms, or use proper separation of concerns and use events / databinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you create a new worker:

```
Worker work = new Worker();
```

But when you create a worker you create a new form:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
```

And it goes on and on until it breaks.

Remove Worker work = new Worker(); from Form 1. Change your Form 1 constructor like this:

```
Worker _worker;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _worker = new Worker(this);
}
```

Change your worker like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    Form1 _form1;
    public Worker(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }
    ...
```

And remove Form1 frm1 = new Form1() from your worker.